# Inseri um html em uma tabela usando sql server

Tags: sql-server

Como poderia fazer um insert em uma tabela de um código HTML?

Exemplo:

```
insert into TB_CONTEUDO (CONT_TITULO, CONT_HTML, CONT_COCA_FK_ID, CONT_META_TAG)
values('Teste','',17,'')
```

`CONT_HTML = html` de uma página

Answer (score 0):

**Tente o seguinte**

Coloque tudo em uma variável, e supondo que você tenha está variável:

```
var html = "<html><body>Html aqui</body></html>"
```

E no insert faça o seguinte:

```
insert into TB_CONTEUDO (CONT_TITULO, CONT_HTML, CONT_COCA_FK_ID, CONT_META_TAG)
values('Teste',?,17,''), [html]
```

Não tenho certeza de que vai funcionar pois estou longe do meu notebook, mas tenta depois me diz, se não funcionar eu edito a resposta :)

Answer (score -1):

Dá mesma maneira na qual você escreveu aqui, você vai salvar esse campo como estivesse salvando uma *String* normalmente, a única preocupação que você deve ter é a de verificar se o seu conteúdo do HTML **não ultrapassa o limite de caracteres do seu campo**.

Um ótimo tipo para salvar seu conteúdos HTML no SQL Server, seria o `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

```
insert into TB_CONTEUDO (CONT_TITULO, CONT_HTML, CONT_COCA_FK_ID, CONT_META_TAG)
values('Teste','<html><body>seu conteúdo html</body></html>',17,'')
```

Comment: em um html pequeno eu também sei, o porque que e grande

Comment: @itasouza O HTML não é nada mais que um texto e no caso deve ser inserido como se fosse um texto. Caso seu html seja grande é bom utilizar seu campo como Nvarchar(Max), para ele caber normalmente. Caso o Nvarchar n te atenda, pode usar um campo do tipo text por exemplo.